# How to iterate linearly over hashtable(array) in php and print the values of its keys and values?

Tags: php

I use

```
foreach($terms as $one)
    {
        print $one."<br>";
    }
```

But this only prints the values. What about the keys?

Comment: This has been answered lots of times before. Try to use the search field on the top right next time.

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the [Language Reference in the PHP Manual](http://de.php.net/manual/en/langref.php), especially the [chapter on control structures](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php) and the [subchapter on foreach](http://de.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
foreach($terms as $key => $one)
{
    print $key . ' ' . $one . '<br>';
}
```

By adding `$key =>` to the `foreach`, you will be able to access the key as `$key` above.